# Boolean expression for checking if expression matches pattern in Rust

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, matching

I have a `Vec` of values and want to `filter` those that match a certain pattern.
What is the idiomatic way to just check *if* an expression matches a pattern, without necessarily doing something with the match?

```rust
enum Kind {
    A,
    B(char),
}

let vector: Vec<Option<Kind>> = ...;
vector.filter(|item| /* check if item matches pattern Some(Kind::B(_)) */)
```

I know I can use the `match` keyword:

```rust
vector.filter(|item| match item {
  Some(Kind::B(_)) => true,
  _ => false,
})
```

or the `if let` keyword:

```rust
vector.filter(|item| {
  if let Some(Kind::B(_)) = item {
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
})
```

But in both examples, the code still looks bulky because I manually need to provide the `true` and `false` constants.
I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do that, something similar to the following:

```rust
vector.filter(|item| matches(item, Some(Kind::B(_))))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a macro named [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.matches.html) for that!

```rust
vector.filter(|item| matches!(item, Some(Kind::B(_))))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer since you cannot store "patterns" in regular variables. Hence, macro variables are required to store patterns.

Comment: Worth noting that the `matches!` macro [was only stabilized in the latest version of Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1420-2020-03-12) (1.42.0) less than a month ago, so depending on when Rust was last updated it might reuqire an update to be able to use this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Option::is_some` function.
Here is example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Kind {
    A,
    B(char),
}

fn main() {
    let vec_of = vec![Some(Kind::A), Some(Kind::B('x')), None, None];

    // let col: Vec<Option<Kind>> = vec_of.into_iter().filter(Option::is_some).collect();
    let col: Vec<Option<Kind>> = vec_of.into_iter().filter(|item| item.is_some()).collect();

    println!("{:?}", col);
}
```

Commend line is the same as one with `.filter(|item| item.is_some())` but shorter. I left longer version too for better understanding.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=088985779ea5bf79dc15b4bd734b808a)

Comment: That only works for `Option` though, not for content inside it. For example, I can't check for the pattern in the question, which is `Some(Kind::B(_))` 